# Derivative of $\ln (z), z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(z) = \ln z := \ln |z| + \arg (z)i$. Then the derivative is (if it exists) by definition:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln (z+h)-\ln (z)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln |z+h| +\arg(z+h)i-\ln |z| -\arg(z)i }{h}$$

Comment: Have you seen the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: what's $u(x,y), v(x,y)$ here?

Comment: You wrote $\ln z = \ln |z| + i \arg z$; notice that $\ln |z|$ and $\arg z$ are real, so $u$ and $v$ are...?

Comment: oh, $u =\ln |z|\cos \arg(z)$ and $v =\ln |z|\sin\arg z$

Comment: Almost; in $i\arg z$, $\arg z$ is real so...

Comment: ok, but that helps to solve the mystery whether $f$ is differentiable unless it also lets us compute the derivative?

Comment: Checking the Cauchy-Riemann equations will give you differentiability but you can also use it to find the derivative; I can elaborate in an answer if necessary?

Comment: please do so, Please explain in general case, thanks.

Comment: the derivative of the principal branch of $\ln z$ on $\mathbb{C}$ is $\frac{d\ln (x+iy)}{dx} = \frac{1}{x+iy}$, $\frac{d\ln (x+iy)}{dy} = \frac{i}{x+iy} + 2 i \pi \delta(y) H(x)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta and $H$ the Heaviside function, and $2 i \pi \delta(y) H(x)$ is the branch cut on $]0;\infty[$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll use $\log$ for the complex logarithm and $\ln$ for the real-valued logarithm; you then have:
$$\log z = \ln |z| + i \arg z = \ln r + i\varphi$$
where I use $r = |z|$ and $\varphi = \arg z$ for simplicity. In this form, we have written
$$\log z = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
with  $u(x,y) = \ln r = \ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \tfrac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)$ and $v(x,y) = \varphi$.

You can check the Cauchy-Riemann equations yourself and find (*)
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} \quad ; \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} = - \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}$$
Use this to find the derivative directly:
$$\frac{\mbox{d} \log z}{\mbox{d}z} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{z}$$

Remark: depending on how you *define* the complex logarithm, there will be different ways to find its derivative.

---

(*) The derivatives for $u$ are easy. For $v$, we have:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
x = r\cos\varphi \\
y = r\sin\varphi
\end{array}\right.$$
where both $r$ and $\varphi$ are (implicit) functions of $x$ and $y$. Differentiating both equations w.r.t. $x$ gives:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 = \cos\varphi\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}-r\sin\varphi\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} \\
0 = \sin\varphi\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+r\cos\varphi\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}
\end{array}\right.$$
This is a linear system of two equations in the variables $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}$; solve for $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}$. In the same way, take the derivative w.r.t. $y$ and solve for $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: confused about one bit. Namely how do you take the partial derivative of $\varphi$? I can't see any expression that lets you say its partial with respect to $y$ is exactly that.

Comment: I didn't work that out; use $x = r\cos\varphi$ and $y = r\sin\varphi$; e.g. continue by taking the derivative (implicit differentiation) w.r.t. $x$ of both equations and solve the system you obtain for $\tfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}$, etc.

Comment: Alright, I will work on, it,  thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, I edited - that happens when you submit before checking what you wrote ;o).

Comment: StackTD one problem arises, when we consider $\varphi =\arctan (y/x)$, depending on the quadrant we sometimes have to add or subtract $\pi$, would that affect anything$

Comment: If you calculate the derivatives from the polar formulas above (with implicit differentiation), there's no need for an explicit formula for $\varphi$, so you can avoid the trouble with $\arctan$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36142/discussion-between-alvin-lepik-and-stacktd).

Comment: You need to restrict the domain here inasmuch as the complex logarithm isn't even continuous in the plane.

Comment: I'm assuming the usual domain is taken ($\mathbb{C} \setminus \{x \;\vert \; x\le 0 \}$).

Comment: @StackTD Many thanks for taking the time, I've worked it out and understand now :)

Comment: The derivative, however, by my calculations is $f'(z) = u_x(x,y) + iv_x(x,y)$

Comment: Correct, that was a typo! Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Let $ U =\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0].$ Then $f(z)=\ln |z| + i\arg z$ is continuous on $U$ and we have $e^{f(z)} = z$ there. This shows $f(z)$ is injective on $U.$ Fix $z\in U.$ Then for small nonzero $h$ we have

$$1=\frac{e^{f(z+h)}-e^{f(z)}}{h} = \frac{e^{f(z+h)}-e^{f(z)}}{f(z+h) - f(z)}\frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h}.$$

The injectivity of $f$ shows that $f(z+h) - f(z)\ne 0,$ so we're OK dividing by it above. As $h\to 0, f(z+h) \to f(z)$ by the continuity of $f.$ So the first difference quotient on the right tends to the derivative of $e^w$ at $w=e^{f(z)},$ which is $e^{f(z)} = z \ne 0.$ Knowing all of this, we can now write

$$\tag 1 \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{e^{f(z+h)}-e^{f(z)}} = \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h}.$$

Since the left side of $(1) \to 1/z,$ we get $f'(z) = 1/z$ (as expected).

Comment: Nicely written.  +1... Mark

Comment: Hey MV, thanks. MSE is interesting in that I'm not sure I ever saw your comment before. But someone upvoted this today, and so here I am. Best to you.

Comment: You're welcome Z!  As for MSE ... Now I know we're not in Kansas anymore.  Best wishes back at you.