# Spectral density of non-Hermitian random matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

I have a question regarding the computation of the spectral density of some non-Hermitian random $N\times N$ matrix $A$. Following [Rogers and Castillo, 2009](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.79.012101), we denote the collection of eigenvalues of $A$ by $\{\lambda_i^A: i = 1,\ldots,N\}$, and for a point in the complex plane $z = x+iy$ we can therefore write the spectral density as
$$
\varrho_A(z,\bar{z}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \delta(x-\Re(\lambda_i^A)) \delta(y-\Im( \lambda_i^A)),
$$
with $\Re(\ldots)$ and $\Im(\ldots)$ the real and imaginary parts respectively.

They proceed by following previous works and define a matrix
$$
H = H(z,\bar{z}; \kappa) = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \kappa I_N & i(z I_N - A) \\
    i(z I_N - A)^\dagger & \kappa I_N
  \end{pmatrix},
$$
with $I_N$ the $N\times N$ identity matrix, and $(\ldots)^\dagger$ the conjugate-transpose. They do not specify $\kappa$, but I assume $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}$, as they later take the limit $\kappa \rightarrow 0$.
Then they define the [Wirting derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives)
$$
\partial_z = \frac{1}{2}\left( \partial_x - i\partial_y\right), \quad
\partial_{\bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \partial_x + i\partial_y\right),
$$
and state that the spectral density can thus be written as
$$
\varrho_A(z,\bar{z}) = -\frac{1}{\pi N} \lim_{\kappa \rightarrow 0} \partial_{\bar{z}}\partial_z \log \det H.
$$

I simply cannot figure out why this is true. One of the example references by [Feinberg, Zee, 1997](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9703087.pdf) notes that $\partial_z (\bar{z})^{-1} = \pi \delta(x)\delta(y)$ (I can also not figure this out), and that from this (and other relations) follows that $\partial_z\partial_{\bar{z}} \log(z\bar{z}) = \pi \delta(x)\delta(y)$ and hence the spectral distribution can be written as
$$
\varrho_A(z,\bar{z}) = \frac{1}{\pi N} \partial_z \partial_\bar{z} \text{Tr} \log (z - A)(\bar{z} - A^\dagger)
$$
Note that this has a very high abuse of notation, but I assume the trace is taken over the log of the product.

How is the form of the spectral density $\varrho_A(z,\bar{z})$ derived in both cases? And why is $\partial_z\partial_{\bar{z}} \log(z\bar{z}) = \pi \delta(x)\delta(y)$? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same notation for integers and matrices is a bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

Your questions about the delta function via the Wirtinger calculus are partially addressed  here:
[Dirac delta distribution in the complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4660234/dirac-delta-distribution-in-the-complex-plane/4660297#4660297)

In more detail, if we set $ g= \log( z\overline z +\epsilon)$ then the Wirtinger derivative rules tell us that

(i)  $g_{\overline z}= \frac{  z}{z\overline z+ \epsilon}$  and from there one next proceeds as in the referenced link to deduce

$g_{z\overline z} $ tends to a delta function at the origin as the parameter $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: I can accept that $\partial_z 1/\bar{z} = \pi \delta(x) \delta(y)$, but this still does not lead me to accept the relation $\partial_z\partial_{\bar{z}} \log(z\bar{z}) = \pi \delta(x)\delta(y)$. Funnily enough, while the example ref. mentions that $\partial_z \log z \neq 1/z$, some have pointed out that it is true (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669153/derivative-of-ln-z-z-in-mathbbc)). So what am I missing?

Comment: Edited so that now you see where $log(z\overline z)$ enters the story.